# How boundary conditions for a green function is same a original function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics, greens-function

I am trying to study green's function.suppose we have a differential equation,

$D_x f(x) =g(x)$ , We also provided with some boundary conditions for $f(x)$, But we supply this boundary conditions in green function for finding constants in green function, actually green function is the position representation of inverse of $D_x$ .

So my question is how is it possible to supply boundary conditions of $f(x)$ in $G(x,x')$ to find constants in $G(x,x')$.

Please  give your precious little time to help me