# Fundamental property of Green's function is violated

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics, greens-function

> **$$\langle x| D|x'\rangle=D_x\langle x|x'\rangle=D_x\,\delta(x-x')$$**

$DD^{-1} = I$  , Where '$I$ ' represents the Identity

position representation of this equation is

$\langle x|D|x'\rangle \langle x|D^{-1}|x'\rangle=\langle x|I|x'\rangle=\delta(x-x')$

this is equivalent to

$\langle x|D|x'\rangle G(x,x')=\delta(x-x')$

Where $G(x,x')$ represents Green's function

This can be written using first equation as

$D_x\,\delta(x-x')G(x,x')=\delta(x-x')$

This shows fundamental property of green function that is

$D_x\,G(x,x')=\delta(x-x')$ is wrong ,

I don't Know where I am wrong, please clear my misconcept by spending your very precious little time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\delta(x-x')
= \langle x | x' \rangle
= \langle x | I | x' \rangle
= \langle x | D D^{-1} | x' \rangle 
= \int \langle x | D | x'' \rangle \langle x'' | D^{-1} | x' \rangle \, dx'' \\
= \int \langle x | D | x'' \rangle G(x'',x') \, dx''
= \int \langle x | x'' \rangle \partial_{x''} G(x'',x') \, dx'' \\
= \int \delta(x-x'') \partial_{x''} G(x'',x') \, dx''
= \partial_{x} G(x,x')
$$

Comment: Nice explanation@md2perpe

Comment: @RobinRaj. Your error was already when you wrote $\langle x|D|x'\rangle \langle x|D^{-1}|x'\rangle$ where you missed the integral. (You also put the variables in the wrong order, but that didn't make a big error in this case.)

Comment: Can you try to answer this question also it would so helpful to me ,   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3255816/how-boundary-conditions-for-a-green-function-is-same-a-original-function  @md2perpe